# How to update a nested collection_check_box

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a form for a child (`categorization`) nested within the parent form (`project`).  The `categorization` attributes are created using a `collection_check_boxes` helper like so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :categorizations do |cat| %>
  <%= collection_check_boxes :categorization, :category_id, @categories, :id, :display_name  %>
<% end %>
```

In the Projects controller I'm able to successfully create the new records:

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  valid_categorizations = params[:categorization][:category_id].reject! { |c| c.empty?}
  @project.categorizations.build(valid_categorizations.map{|cat| {category_id: cat}})
  ...
  end

...
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:slug, :title, :body, :published, :category_ids => [])
end
```

Now, when I want to edit the parent Project record the `collection_check_boxes` does two undesirable things:

1. It does not pre-populate attributes (like the `.include?(attribute)` in a traditional check box), and
2. It repeats the set of check boxes N times depending on how many `categorization` records exist in the database (e.g., if Project #1 has three Categorization records the entire set of check boxes will display three times in the edit form).

I can't figure out how to fix this, so any help is greatly appreciated!